# Only allow numbers, plus, minus, comma, F5 and more

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'm trying to block all key strokes besides numbers (both those over the characters and the ones on the numpad) and the minus (-) and plus (+) signs and the comma (,).

As it is now, it only types twice of that I type in (e.g. 2 is 22) and it also replaces the current value with the new number but for the plus, minus, and comma, it insert ½, m, and k. I also want to unblock the typical keys that are well used on a website, such as F5, Ctrl + R, Shift + R, delete, home and end, but I don't know how I can unblock F5, Shift + R, and Ctrl + R.

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input[name="textfield-correction-temperature"]', function(c) {
    console.log(c.keyCode);
    if(c.keyCode != 107 && c.keyCode != 109 && c.keyCode != 188 && c.keyCode > 31 && (c.keyCode < 48 || c.keyCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var key = String.fromCharCode(c.which);
        $(this).val(key);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/ckufywqv/)

Comment: For the first issue: you return false for undesired input (which is OK), but then manually add input if it's valid, without cancelling it. This means you add a character, and the system adds a character, resulting in duplicates. You should always return false.

Comment: That fixed the issue about the duplicated value :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this same process using a regular expression might help to simply your code a little.

Here's an example of one that uses a regular expression to block out anything that is not a number:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('keydown', 'input[name="textfield-correction-temperature"]', function(c) {

        if (String.fromCharCode(c.keyCode).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') == '') {
            return false;
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textfield-correction-temperature" tabindex="0" maxlength="6">
```

You could, of course, modify the regex to your liking, easily swapping out acceptable/unacceptable characters.

Comment: Thanks but how can I allow the numbers on the numpad with the regex?

Comment: The jsfiddle I included in the post should show an example of it working with a number pad. The regular expressions for other keycodes (like backspace) can be found [here](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx).